# I will want to use my connection to my database as a function that I can use in my other pages

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Here is the code I am currently running, including two functions `connect_database` and `disconnect_database`

```php
function connect_database(){
    try {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test1;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $bdd;
};

function disconnect_database($request){
    $request->closeCursor();
};
```

Comment: So what's the problem ?

Comment: Your question is not clear but if your goal is to use these functions, you can just save them in a file, let's say `connection.php` and then include this file in all your other files.

Comment: With this method it does not work I wanted to know if I wrongly wrote the code of the function?

Answer (score 0):

create a database class lets say

```
class Database {

  public function connect(){
    // connect
    return $connection;
  }

  public function close(){
    // disconnect 
  }

}
```

then include it to the module you want to connect to database.

```
$database = new Database();
$connection = $database->connect();
$database->close();
```

Comment: I am really beginner in php I do not yet understand the subtleties of the class. on the other hand an approach with functions would be the best for me thank you

Comment: If you're on procedural approach, use including php file instead. :)